# Simple Client-Server application with Blacklist verification by Network

Tags: java, sockets, networking, client-server

I'm building a simple Client-Server application and I wanted to implement some kind of Blacklist verification to it.

Currently I have an IP Blacklist verification working, which reads a String from a file (blacklist.txt), and compares it to the socket IP address. If its equal, the client is rejected.

What I wanted to implement now is some kind of Network Blacklist verification instead of IP.

Lets say I have 192.168.1.0/24 on my "blacklist.txt". I needed to block any connections from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255.

This is the code I have for the IP Blacklist verification at the moment:

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Joao\\git\\ProjectoRedes\\lists\\blacklist.txt"));
        String line = null;
        socket = server.accept();

        // Blacklist verification - Do in single thread
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.equals(socket.getInetAddress().toString())) {
                System.out.println("IP Blacklisted: " + socket.getInetAddress().toString());
                System.out.println("Closing connection to " + socket.getInetAddress().toString());
                PrintStream checkBlack = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                checkBlack.println("***BLACKLISTED***");
                reader.close();

                socket.close();
                break; 
            }
        }
```

The output is then sent to the Client, which closes the socket, terminating the connection.

I'd like to know if there is any simple way to do what I said above.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure there's a much better way, but you could do a `String#substring` to extract only the significant parts of the IP address and compare them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
int ip = ip2int(socket.getInetAddress().getHostName());

// iterate over black list, split item into subnet and bits
String line = "192.168.1.0/24";
String[] a = line.split("/");
int subnet = ip2int(a[0]);
// make a mask
int bits = a.length == 1 ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(a[1]);
int mask = 0xFFFFFFFF << 32 - bits;
// mask client ip and compare
if ((ip & mask) == subnet) {
// match
}
```

this is ip -> int func

```
int ip2int(String ip) throws UnknownHostException {
    InetAddress a = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
    return  new BigInteger(a.getAddress()).intValue();
}
```

Comment: If i'm reading correctly, this only solves what I already have solved, even though it may be faster. I'm not looking for a faster solution, though. I'm looking for a way to read a 'network' (192.168.1.0/24) and from there exclude all the IPs from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255, without adding them manually to the list.

Comment: Yes, I think this will do it, even though I'm still struggling to understand the "make a mask" part. Another thing, on `if ((ip & mask) == subnet)` what's the `ip` variable ?

Comment: Sure, but I mean, can't compare it in the form of an `InetAddress`, which form should I put it there in ?

Comment: So basically its `if ((subnet & mask) == subnet)` ?

Comment: No. subnet is a next ip address from blacklist and we compare it to the client ip but without the lower bits. this is why we use mask